# PHP Regex pattern to get a specify word

Tags: php, regex

i have some strings result of `var_dump` like this :

```
string(5) "tes37"
string(6) "SRV410"
string(6) "SRV400"
string(6) "SRV311"
string(6) "SRV302"
string(6) "SRV301"
string(6) "SRV300"
string(6) "SRV001"
string(7) "SRV_123"
string(5) "sad34"
string(7) "S 0001J"
string(8) "S 00004J"
string(8) "S 00003J"
string(8) "S 00002J"
string(6) "asdasd"
string(4) "4356"
string(3) "234"
```

here i want to get string with regex such as : 
S 0001J, S 00002J, S 00003J and S00004J

anyone can help me out to make the pattern regex ? 
Thank you

Comment: Try using `S\s*\d+J` ... but you show include the code you are using, because without seeing that, we maybe can't suggest an exact pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the number of zeros in the string, you can use the following regex:

```
S 0+[1-9]J
```

Change the `+` to a quantifier of the form `{number, number}` if you want to keep the number of zeros within a specific number. For example, if you want between three to five zeros, you can do `S 0{3,5}[1-9]J`.

Of course, this is assuming the string is following the format `S (a number of zeros)(a digit)J`